# How to convert string to list in JSONPath notation?

Tags: jsonpath, aws-step-functions

[image: stepfunctionscreenshot]

The JSON in line 5 in the Parameters section of the screenshot uses JSONPath notation in AWS Step Functions. The key is `"Values.$"` and the value is a JSONPath that selects a string `"$"`. However, I need to pass in a LIST not a STRING. The value that `$` selects is a string.

If I put brackets around, it no longer recognizes that I'm using JSONPath notation and simply passes in the dollar sign character instead of gets the value from inputs.

How can I use JSONPath notation and pass in a string as a list?

Comment: I'm not sure how `Values.$` or step function definitions work, but have you tried `$[*]`? `$` is just the start of a path. It returns the whole value. I expect adding `[*]` would get the items in an array.  Can you show an example of what you're expecting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jsonPath inside array in AWS Step Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59167287/how-to-use-jsonpath-inside-array-in-aws-step-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to use the `States.Array` Intrinsic Function since `Parameters` is a [Payload Template](https://states-language.net/spec.html#payload-template)

```json
{
  "Filters": [{
    "Name": "replication-task-arn",
    "Values.$": "States.Array($)"
  }],
  "MaxRecords": 20,
  "WithoutSettings": true
}
```